# Approved suggested edits not rewarding +2 reputation

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I proposed the following suggested edits today that were approved:

- [Suggested edit 1](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/272456)
- [Suggested edit 2](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/272453)

I am still under 2000 reputation.  Shouldn't I have received +2 reputation for at least one of them?

Comment: It's moot now anyway; you passed 2000 a mere four hours after you asked the above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [the help center](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation):

> suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)

A quick look at your profile:

- questions and answers should be worth around ~900 reputation (tentatively more because one upvote and one downvote nets +3 reputation)
- you have created ~540 suggested edits

So it's likely you've had 500 edits approved at 2 reputation each, and hit the limit.

Comment: Ahh, must have missed that.  I am indeed over 500 suggested edits.